# How to disable "You have gone full screen" box?

Tags: google-chrome, fullscreen

My web-app needs to go full screen in Chrome. If I do that below box shows up when my cursor is near top of the screen. Can I somehow made this box inactive and go to full full-screen?
[image: chrome full screen box with F11]

Answer (score 0):

After some further research I found the Chrome has the kiosk mode. It can be enabled with command line flag:

```
google-chrome --kiosk www.web.page.com
```

In kiosk mode the F11 box doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

Use Firefox or Opera... I am sorry, but that's the only option so far.

Answer (score 0):

The --kiosk setting didn't work for me, but I found I can do 

`google-chrome --app="url"`

then fullscreen it in the window manager, `--app` removes the toolbars.